# aiohttp websocket EOfStream handling

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm connecting to a websocket endpoint using [aiohttp's](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) default WebsocketProtocol and out of the blue (after some time and multiple infinite loop iterations) I always get `WSMsgType.ERROR` with `EofStream` as data. To my understanding, this should not happen. I tried researching how to deal with this but have been relatively unsuccessful. Should I just close and reconnect to the endpoint? Is there a way to ensure this doesn't happen? Should I implement a specific handling algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means connection closed by peer.
Internet is unstable transport, you should always be prepared to such situations.
Usually reconnection helps in cases like this.

Comment: Shouldn't I be getting a CLOSE WSMsgType message first ?

Comment: It depends. 
Close is sent by standard disconnection initiated by peer.
Network problems might not signal by CLOSE.
That's how TCP protocol works, the problem is not specific to websockets only.